# How to create a tabs-like menu but then slightly different in React app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, toggle, show-hide

I have multiple pages in my React app where I want to have this functionality. So in a certain React page I add `CopyToClipboard` and the `children` TabIcon:

```
<CopyToClipboard>
  <TabIcon type="link" title="Test one" />
  <TabIcon type="embed" title="Test two" />
</CopyToClipboard>
```

In another page I maybe have only:

```
<CopyToClipboard>
  <TabIcon type="link" title="Test one" />
</CopyToClipboard>
```

The `TabIcon` component:

```
const TabIcon = ({ title, type, onClick }: Props) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const styles = Styles({ theme });

  return (
    <li>
      <ButtonBase type="button" onClick={onClick} title={title} disableRipple>
        <span css={styles.icon}>{type === 'embed' ? <EmbedIcon /> : <LinkIcon />}</span>
      </ButtonBase>
    </li>
  );
};
```

The `CopyToClipboard` component:

```
const CopyToClipboard = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isCopied, setIsCopied] = useState(false);

  const stringToCopy =
    type === 'link'
      ? `https://www.mysite${path}`
      : `<iframe>// iframe code etc here</iframe>`;

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsOpen((current) => !current);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {children.map((item) => (
          <TabIcon type={item.type} onClick={handleClick} />
        ))}
      </ul>
      {isOpen && (
        <div>
          <p>{stringToCopy}</p>
          <ButtonBase type="button" onClick={handleCopyClick} disableRipple>
            <span>{isCopied ? `${suffix} copied` : `Copy ${suffix}`}</span>
            <span>{isCopied ? <CheckIcon /> : <CopyIcon />}</span>
          </ButtonBase>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CopyToClipboard;
```

So what I like to achieve is the following:

- When clicking a button it toggles/shows the correct div with its associated content. When clicking the same button again it hides the `div`. When clicking the other button it shows the associated content of that button. When you click that button again it hides the div.

How to achieve this within my example?

Answer (score 1):

You need a single state (`text`). If the `text` has a truthy value (actual text in this case), the `div` is displayed.

When you set the text, the `handleClick` compares the `prevText` and the new text (`txt`), and if they are equal it sets `null` as the value of `text`, which hides the `div`. If they are not equal, the new text is set, and the `div` is displayed.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Demo = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = txt => {
    setText(prevText => prevText === txt ? null : txt);
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button onClick={() => handleClick('Button 1 text')}>
            Button 1
          </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onClick={() => handleClick('Button 2 text')}>
            Button 2
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      {text && (
        <div>
          <p>{text}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I updated my question. You may have an idea? Thanks